# How to position my text inside div when using z-index for overlapping?

Tags: html, css

How to position my text inside div whe using z-index for overlapping.

I needed to recreate this:

[image]

I could reproduced the text part but it is positioned outside div (gray background):

[image]

How can I just move the text up?

**Bonus:**

How can I expand the div with red border to the left, near the text (to move up)?

**Codepen:**

https://codepen.io/ogonzales/pen/qBOYrQy

**Code:**

```
<div id="header"><!-- flex container -->

  <div class="box" id="bluebox" style="margin-left: 0%;"><!-- flex item -->
    <div>
      <div id="element-1" class="element">ELIM</div>
      <div id="element-2" class="element">ONLINE</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="redbox"><!-- flex item -->
      <p style="background-color: black; color: white;">EXPANDIENDO LA PALABRA DE DIOS POR TODO EL MUNDO</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is what you meant? But you can instead just reduce the line-height to get the text lines closer together; instead of having separate elements, shifting with margin and changing z-index.

Like so:

```
.title {
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

Where:

```
<div class="title">
  <div>ELIM</div>
  <div>ONLINE</div>
</div>
```

```css
#header {
  display: flex; /* establish flex container */
  flex-direction: row; /* make main axis horizontal (default value) */
  justify-content: center; /* center items horizontally, in this case */
  align-items: center; /* center items vertically, in this case */
  height: 200px; /* for demo purposes */
  border: 1px solid black; /* for demo purposes */
  background-color: #eee; /* for demo purposes */
}

.box {
  width: 400px;
  margin: 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

.elim_online {
  font-size: 3.9em;
}

#bluebox { 
  background: aqua;
}
#redbox { 
  border: solid red;
  background:
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 0 100px,green 100px 102px) 0 0,
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 0 140px,green 140px 142px) 0 0/100% 80%,
    repeating-linear-gradient(-45deg,transparent 0 120px,green 120px 122px) 40px 10%/100% 50%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}

.title {
  font-size: 75px;
  line-height: 0.8em;
}
```

```html
<div id="header"><!-- flex container -->

  <div class="box" id="bluebox" style="margin-left: 0%;"><!-- flex item -->
    <div class="title">
      <div>ELIM</div>
      <div>ONLINE</div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="box" id="redbox"><!-- flex item -->
      <p style="background-color: black; color: white;">EXPANDIENDO LA PALABRA DE DIOS POR TODO EL MUNDO</p>
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: Yes, that is Matt. Could you make it so the red div gets closer to the blue div? Like in the image posted on the original question.

Comment: To do that you just need to reduce the margin that is applied to your box class. I've reduced it in my example

Comment: Matt, yes, but now the text in the lightblue div is again close to the red div. It should be left aligned. Do you mind telling me why? So it should be left aligned, and the red div expanded to that space left by the lightblue div. Hope I made myself clear.